# Which criteria allows motels to take role in the Supernatural series?

Tags: supernatural, set-design

By looking Supernatural I saw a lot of fancy motel rooms.

For example:

- one full of hunters trophies and oil paintings
- one with a lot of glass, even the room separator was glass

If I think back, all of the rooms had a theme...

My question is: May there be a record, why and how this rooms were selected?

Comment: Downvoters, please help me to improve my question...

Comment: @Paulie_D For me to learn: Why have you edited like you do?

Comment: The question didn't need the issue of whether *actual* motels have themed rooms as it's secondary to your actual primary question. There would be no harm in **another** question about the [tag:realism] of these sets but frankly that's something you could easily search for. There are a great many "themed" roadside hotels in the US.

Comment: @Paulie_D What I intendet with this question was this: Is it common, that this rooms are so "themed" or is it all set-design? Now I know: it is both. There are themed rooms, but this for supernatural are all additional designed to fit the plot

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in this [wiki post](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/Motels:_Season_1):

> The sets are always excellent, with wonderful attention to detail, the work of Production Designer Jerry Wanek and Art Director John Marcynuk. [...] Jensen said of the motel rooms: "Jerry Wanek's just a crazy guy, and likes to use his talents when he gets the ability to, and the motel rooms are his passion.